Не строится проект в Android studio
Проект в Android Studio написан на flutter, при попытке выполнить flutter build apk, в консоли появляется надпись:
 Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2 886ms √ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (17.9MB)
Но app-release.apk не меняется и остается изначального размера с изначальным наполнением.
В то же время на встроенном телефоне приложение работает нормально и обновляется при каждом запуске.
Проект на flutter doctor проверял
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4651], locale ru-RU)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.37)
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found! 

Ошибок не найдено, flutter clean не принесло изменений, пробовал построить другие проекты, ни на каком из них не сработало.
Android studio запускал как администратор - раньше это помогало, сейчас нет- ответьте пожалуйста что делать в такой ситуации, возможно у кого то была такая ситуация.

Удалите папку build и выполните flutter build apk
